# Will getting the current date/time be thread-safe in C++20?

Tags: c++, date, datetime, time, c++20

**Short Question**

Up to and including C++17, C++ provides no thread-safe way to get the current time or date. Will this be fixed in C++20?

**Long Question**

The only portable way to get the current time and date is by using the std::gmtime or std::localtime functions. Remnants from the early days of C, these functions convert a given time since an implementation-defined epoch into calender time (for example, 1515153600 into Fri, 05 Jan 2018 12:00:00 GMT). The only downside, however, is that those functions return a pointer to an internal static variable and aren't threadsafe. What's even worse is that this static variable may be shared by all related functions such as std::gmtime, std::localtime, and std::ctime and may be overwritten on each invocation of any of those functions. So if you're using threads and want to regularly check the time you risk data races and undefined behavior.

**Clearly the current standard is broken in this regard. Is there any effort by the C++ standard committee to fix this situation and how likely is this going to be included in C++20?**

Comment: Regarding the chrono solution, Howard's `<date>` proposal is progressing well.

Comment: I don't see how adding thread-safe time functions will solve your problem of "But now you have to make sure that every bit of your code actually goes through the mutex wrapper. If it doesn't you can again get data races and hence undefined behavior. If you're coding on large projects where coding work is divided into teams, you have to continously remind everyone that they should not (!) use the functions provided by the C++ standard, but use your own wrapper instead (or risk undefined behavior)." You still have to tell people not to use the non-thread-safe functions.

Comment: @NicolBolas That is true. My point was that when this is fixed coders can use the thread safe functions provided by the C++ standard and in a threaded environment there is no reason not to. Sure, they can still shoot themselves in the foot, but now they have a standard-provided option _not_ to shoot themselves in the foot. And having the C++ standard provide these functions has the added benefit that it _may_ be internally implemented without any locks.

Comment: #2 is what my proposal is aiming for:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0355r4.html#time.clock.system

Comment: As I write this there are 3 close votes.  If this gets closed, I hereby pledge to vote to reopen.  I encourage others to comment likewise if they feel so inclined.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Why would 3 people want to close this question? What's wrong with it? If it's too long, I'm happy to make it shorter. By the way, nice work on your proposal, I'm just reading through it and it is very good indeed.

Comment: @NicolBolas Done. Edited it to make it shorter and more to the point. Thank you for your input. :)

Comment: You can see my answer here ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436060/how-to-get-timestamp-in-c/41192442#41192442

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) *is* what's coming for C++20. It was proposed via [p0355r4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0355r4.html) and approved for C++20 in Nov. 2017. Is it thread safe? Unfortunately, neither the documentation nor proposal seem to be clear on this. However, certain functions like `get_tzdb_list` are explicitly said to have "Thread Safety". Your best option is to ask Hinnant himself in the [gitter](https://gitter.im/HowardHinnant/date?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge) chat. However, discussion in [Why is there no C++11 threadsafe alternative to std::localtime and std::gmtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25618702) seems to suggest that it is thread-safe (even though it's never explicitly said). As Nicol Bolas [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106291/will-getting-the-current-date-time-be-thread-safe-in-c20#comment83188606_48106425) you can just wrap it behind a mutex.

> If it doesn't you can again get data races and hence undefined behavior. If you're coding on large projects where coding work is divided into teams, you have to continously remind everyone that they should not (!) use the functions provided by the C++ standard, but use your own wrapper instead (or risk undefined behavior).

At a shallow level, this is what code reviews are for. [Facebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkgszkPnV8g) has this problem for junior developers where they keep making the same bugs over and over. If your team has "curiously recurring bugs", you need to address it somehow (like adding checks to linter: Clang comes to mind).

At a much more direct level, [Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzaYUlAw93k) is the epitome of this. The problem they were having was using the old COW implementation of `string` and switching over to SSO-based `string`. However, because they relied on third party libraries that used COW-based `string`, they needed to support both in their codebase. Telling developers to use the Google wrapper was a futile effort. The solution the developer came up with was using a hack with `inline namespaces`. A bit extreme, but if you are dealing with a similarly large codebase, it could do the trick.

### The thread-safe code to get the current time in C++20

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = system_clock::now();
    cout << format("{:%F %T %Z}", now) << '\n';
    cout << format("{:%F %T %Z}", zoned_time{current_zone(), now}) << '\n';
    cout << format("{:%F %T %Z}", zoned_time{"Australia/Sydney", now}) << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
2022-06-09 01:14:31.844518 UTC
2022-06-08 21:14:31.844518 EDT
2022-06-09 11:14:31.844518 AEST
```

This example gets the current time in UTC with `system_clock`, displays that, and then also translates that time into my computer's current local time zone, and into Sydney Australia's current time.

All of it is thread-safe.  You could execute this exact same code in multiple threads and there would be no race condition.

Disclaimer:  As I write this, not all platforms have implemented this part of C++20.  See your std::lib's C++20 status page for more details.

Comment: Note: Even if it's not thread-safe, it neatly solves the problem Lomos has with `chonro` clocks, as the date/times are epoch/platform-independent. So you could just wrap it behind a mutex if it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Very pleased to see this going into C++20, nice work! Is there a way to see which proposals have been approved at which stage? https://isocpp.org/std/status doesn't list anything about this proposal and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/ lists a lot of proposals including this one but doesn't make it obvious what has been included in C++20.

Comment: Hi! (waves :-) ) .  Howard Hinnant's date library and the subsequent proposal for C++ standardization are thread safe!  100% except for the small corner cases that are explicitly documented to be not thread safe.  Those corner cases involve updating the TZ database at run time while the application is still up (in case your application needs to stay up for many months at a time and needs an updated time zone database).  In this latter case, there are tools available to the programmer to traverse this update in a thread safe manner, but it is not out of the box safe.  RTFM.

Comment: You might as well just add that as an answer, since it seems pretty official

Comment: I've upvoted this answer as it says pretty much what I would have said.  And nothing I say is official.  Yes I participate on the committee.  But no, I have no official voice of the committee.  No one does, except the official announcements which Herb makes (and not all of his communications are official announcements).  But thanks for the vote of confidence. :-)

Comment: A nit - Howard's library has been proposed for C++20, but it has not been adopted yet. I would be surprised if it is not adopted, but NOT YET.

Comment: An update: Last week, Howard's proposal (based on his library) was accepted for C++2a (which will probably be c++20).